# Extracting or exporting favourite questions

Tags: support, data-dump, bookmarks, export

Is it possible to export a list or dump of questions that I have favourited from a site?

I've been busy going through the site and along the way I've seen things and thought, "wow, what a good question that is!" And I have duly favourited it.

However, when it comes to finding something from my favourites (starred questions), I have to go through my profile, switch tabs, blah blah blah.

It'd be nice, if it were possible, to extract those favorite questions in terms of their raw data so I can archive them without having to find them in the creative commons data dump that Stack Exchange provides.

I'm sure I heard mention of an API around here somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to do it with this [request](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=users/%7Bid%7D/favorites):

`/users/{id}/favorites`

You'll find all you want and more on the [stackapps](https://stackapps.com/) website, which discusses the api, and probably has exactly what you need.  Chances are someone already has a utility to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Example: [**http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/2/favorites**](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/2/favorites)

If the user has more than 30 favorites, then you can pass "page" parameter to view more pages, like: [**http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/2/favorites?page=2**](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/users/2/favorites?page=2)

You can also pass pagesize parameter to specify the number of results per page (Default: 30).